# Are questions about research topic considered to be on topic on Phys.SE?

Tags: support, scope

I'm interested in working in a PhD research on a particular field. I've talked to a professor that despite his interest in supervising this work he would like me to come up with a few concrete research topics/objectives so that we could discuss about those and pick one.

I'm struggling to do so and considered asking here. I'm afraid the question is closed as off topic or too broad.

So: questions about possible research topics for a PhD are considered to be on topic here? Is there a particular way to ask such a question so that it becomes on topic? Or is it completely hopeless and such a question will no matter how asked be off topic?

Comment: You *could* drop into the h bar and ask, but ... getting any useful answers depends on some denizen of that fey place happening to be conversant with the sub-field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @dmckee. Well it wouldn't hurt to ask there if anyone is familiar with it. Perhaps with a bit of luck I can talk to someone who knows it and is able to give some advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions about suggesting a research topic are not questions that can have an objective answer, nor are they even about *physics as a science* (but as a profession). They are prime examples of questions that are primarily opinion-based and have been considered off-topic for years, cf. e.g. ["What's a good research topic?" questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5061).